# How can I color text with a gradient color which adapts with the screen size and continues the color on the new line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After writing the following code the color stops at the end of the line and starts again at the next line. I want it to continue and end with a different color till it reaches the end of second line. Then continue doing so.

Here is my css class that I am using on a p tag.

```
$font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

.text {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #4ad7fa 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font: {
        size: 3vw;
        family: $font;
    };
}
```

**Here is what I am getting:**

[image]

**And here is what I expect:**

[image]

---

Can I do it without using any javascript?
Although javascript is also fine.

Comment: Might I say, the first one looks better.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I was just thinking, the second one brings me back to MySpace days.

Comment: How can you get red color with this gradient ?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It does, but my motive here is to keep a track of the lines that I am reading. You can read the second one much faster than the first one.

Comment: I'd say that's because it more spaced out and a lighter font rather than because of the gradient.  If anything the gradients just make it harder to read!

Comment: If ease of reading is what you're looking for then a zebra background style will be better, one line gray one white and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add a display : inline, and a few red :

```css
.text {
  display: inline;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, blue 25%, #000 50%, red 75%, #000 100%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, quo consectetur similique blanditiis explicabo dolorum quam voluptate, accusamus repellat sed ipsam doloribus facere quas perspiciatis veritatis ad dicta. Tenetur, vero?
</p>
```

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 0%, blue 25%, #000 50%, red 75%, #000 100%);` and `background-size: 1000px 100%;` is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification !

Comment: OP can adapt `background-size` width to his needs.

Comment: Good job man! I thought this was impossible. Learned something today, thanks :)

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you! This will work for me!

Comment: You're welcome ! I didn't know neither. That was a good exercice.